# Transparent part of SVG wont allow div behind to trigger its on hover

Tags: html, css, svg, vector-graphics

Im looking for a solution to ignore the invisible part of my svg image as it's preventing the hover trigger of a div thats behind it.

```
  .upNextCard{
  /* Rectangle 68 */

  position: absolute;
  width: 214.29px;
  height: 255.69px;
  margin-left:300px;
  margin-top:190px;
  background-color:#E0B21C;
  transform: rotate(-12.08deg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;

}

.upNextCard:hover {
  margin-top: -2px;
}
```

Then my svgs look like this :

```
 <svg style="float:right; height="647" viewBox="0 0 705 447" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <path d="M172.946 231.127C108.638 224.493 30.8536 239.697 0 248.128L109.684 501.942L794.936 205.814L706.277 0.651297C699.086 3.75868 677.418 14.5387 648.27 32.7994C619.123 51.0602 554.376 116.769 525.646 147.341C495.115 175.423 418.745 232.973 357.52 238.515C280.989 245.442 253.331 239.42 172.946 231.127Z" fill="#E6E6E6"/>
      </svg>
      <div id="upNextBanner">
        </div>

      <div class="upNextCard">
        <img src="https://studio.uxpincdn.com/studio/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/Tips-for-Designers-Interested-in-Advanced-UX-UI.png">
        </div>

        <div id="returnToBlog">
          </div>
            </footer>
          <footer>
            <svg height="450" viewBox="0 0 713 276" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M158.295 52.9042C104.35 21.3613 30.288 4.49186 0 0V276H714V52.9042C706.508 52.9042 683.393 54.2018 650.873 59.3924C618.354 64.583 536.576 99.1537 499.752 115.79C462.291 129.432 373.403 151.925 317.546 132.759C247.724 108.803 225.725 92.3327 158.295 52.9042Z" fill="#F4F4F4"></path>
  </svg>
```

[What it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2vau.png)

Comment: set the SVG to pointer-events: none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a quick answer because I do not have a real example, but have you tried to set `pointer-events: none` to the path you don't want to be touchable? Or to the entire SVG, in order to choose manually the elements that can be touchable. Like this:

```
svg {
    pointer-events: none;
}

svg * {
    pointer-events: visible;
}
```

I assume that you want that children of SVG be clickable, but if you don't, just exclude the `pointer-events: none` from those childs you want to be touchable just specifying `pointer-events: visible` on it.

Anything it wasn't specified as `pointer-events: visible` into the parent SVG will inherit this property. So you have to specify `pointer-events: visible` on those element you want to be touchable.

Comment: thank you so much! I'll give this a go.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 1):

A similar alternative approach is to just set the pointer-events of the svg path directly.

In my case I wanted the inside of an odd shaped svg path to trigger the hover event, but not the surrounding rectangular bounding box.  Setting `pointer-events: fill` solved this for me, like the below:

```
.svg-path {
    cursor: pointer;
    pointer-events: fill; /* or bounding-box, or stroke, etc */
}
```

More info on the options can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events